Why does my printer add a "M6" when I print a pdf?
I got forwarded here from the askubuntu forum. Hope you can help:
Recently, I printed a pdf document and I noticed that sometimes on the print there was an additional M6 in the corner that wasn´t on the original document. I printed the page a couple of times, and sometimes it was printed and sometimes not. Is this a common bug? Any ideas to what my have caused this? 
I printed from Document viewer (Xreader), my printer is a HP Deskjet 840 c and my Linux built is Linux Mint 20 Ulyana. My laptop is a HP Pavillion dv7.
Thank you in advance.

You should first test and clarify whether it happens only for Xreader, or for any pdf viewer you tried. Also does it only happen to specific pdfs.
